# What is the "skin type" on a door? Is a door with Silicone Finish "skin type" easily paintable?

Tags: doors

I'm looking at purchasing a few pre-hung interior doors for my basement. The doors say that their "skin type" is Silicone Finish. What is the "skin type" on a door? Is a door with Silicone Finish "skin type" easily paintable?

See what I'm talking about in the [Specifications](https://www.menards.com/main/interior-closet-doors/mastercraft-interior-single-doors/mastercraft-reg-prefinished-craftsman-flat-3-panel-prehung-interior-door/p-1444448319282.htm).

Comment: I'm familiar with door skins used on automobiles (similar to a "skin" for one's phone...an outer layer).  The "Silicone Finish" part seems to indicate there are silicone additives in the paint to improve heat and moisture protection.  But I wouldn't call a layer of paint a "skin".  If the internal structure of the door is wood clad in steel then I might call the skin: "steel" and the paint "silicone based". "Finish" would be flat, matte, eggshell, semi-gloss, gloss, or high-gloss.

Comment: Most common interior doors in the US are hollow.  There is a wood frame, with a thin layer on each side which is the "door skin". Usually wood; sometimes plastic.  The skin material itself would not be silicone; that would be a rubbery sheet.  It is possible that it is painted or primed with something containing silicone, but silicone won't let more paint stick to it. I think the marketing dept is making up nonsense.  Post an actual brand and product name, preferably with a link to a product web page.

Comment: @Grunthos See what I'm talking about in the Specifications below: https://www.menards.com/main/interior-closet-doors/mastercraft-interior-single-doors/mastercraft-reg-prefinished-craftsman-flat-3-panel-prehung-interior-door/p-1444448319282.htm

Comment: Silicone is generally a bad thing in something you want to paint over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many common interior doors in the US are hollow. There is a wood frame, with a thin layer on each side which is the "door skin".  The door may be painted, or stained to let the wood grain show.

Doors that aren't hollow, often known as "solid-core" doors, may have a thin wood veneer layer of better wood on the surface, which also might be called the door skin.

The "finish" will refer to how it is painted or sealed.  Finish can sometimes describe just the appearance of how shiny it is (flat/matte, satin, semi-gloss or gloss finish) or the material or chemicals used for the finish (painted, stained, varnished, or laquered finish).

Stain brings out the natural coloring of the wood but doesn't protect it; it needs a sealer.  The sealer over the stain is often referred to as "varnish", but there are many different chemical compounds that may be used.

In this case, the silicone finish is referring to the type of sealer over the stain.  Probably something similar to [Cabot waterproofing sealer](http://www.cabotstain.com/products/product/Waterproofing.html).

You will NOT have good results in painting over this finish.  Silicone definitely repels other substances.

For a door that you intend to paint, look for something either "unfinished" or "primed".  Unfinished means is just the raw wood with no paint, stain, or sealer.  Primed means it has a base coat of paint primer for protection of the wood during shipping, and it is ready for you to finish painting it.  All other things being equal, go for "primed" over "unfinished" if you are going to paint it, because the primer gives you a head start.